# Angular disable tag for some time if click event is triggered?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

How to restrict user clicking anchor tag multiple times within some time frame?

I need to disable click event for 1 sec after user clicks on anchor tag.

```
 <a (click)="clickMe(Id)">
```

Comment: What do you actaully want to do ? There might be a better way to do it.

Comment: What's the goal ? If you want to fetch some data, maybe you should wait the end of the request, successful or not, to enable again.

Comment: @prince , I am opening new window as drawer on button click , but it takes time to open it with all data (data is coming from third party api) ,  in the meantime , if user is clicking multiple times , multiple windows are opening.

Comment: Create a component property and set it to true just before calling API, also use same property in template to disable button. And when you get the data set that property to false inside the subscribe. Please try this, if you still face any issue, i ll create a stackblitz for you.

Comment: @Ajin: In that case you have to disable the button until the response is received from the API. Not for a fixed time. Please see my update to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `setTimout()` along with `[disabled]` attribute. But like others have pointed out in the comments, restricting user input based on a timeout isn't an elegant solution. It would server you better if you could explain why you would like to disable user input for some time.

```js
export class AppComponent  {
  disableButton = false;

  onClick(event) {
    this.disableButton = true;
    setTimeout(() => { this.disableButton = false }, 3000);
  }
}
```

```
<button [disabled]="disableButton" (mouseup)="onClick($event)">Click me</button>
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ipgmiy)

**Update**

From your comment:

> I am opening new window as drawer on button click , but it takes time
>   to open it with all data (data is coming from third party api) , in
>   the meantime , if user is clicking multiple times , multiple windows
>   are opening.

In that case you need to disable the button not based on a fixed timeout, but till the data is received from the API. Do the following

Component

```js
export class AppComponent  {
  isDataLoading = false;
  label = 'Click me';

  onClick(event) {
    this.setLoadingStatus(true);

    this.http.get('url').subscribe(
      response => {
        this.setLoadingStatus(false);
        // further statements
      },
      error => {
        // handle error
      }
    );
  }

  setLoadingStatus(status: boolean) {
    this.isDataLoading = status;
    this.label = status ? 'Please wait...' : 'Click me';
  }
}
```

Template

```
<button [disabled]="isDataLoading" (mouseup)="onClick($event)">{{label}}</button>
```

**Update 2 - anchor tag**

To disable an anchor tag, set it's `href` attribute based on the loading flag.

```
<a [attr.href]="isDataLoading ? null : 'url here'" (mouseup)="onClick($event)">{{label}}</a>
```

Comment: quick update I am not using button , I am using anchor tag , disable will not be useful in this case.

Comment: In that case set the URL dynamically using the boolean flag. See update to my answer.